What is some opinions of these Torah laws with divorce and remarriage
nature of the woman’s condition that gave rise to the husband’s desire to divorce her? Most of the answers involve some alleged offense on the part of the woman. The offenses suggested range from “adultery” (Shammai’s School) to “anything the husband found offensive” (Hillel’s position). Let us consider the possibilities in order.
… is “adultery”
This was the view of the School of Shammai. Whatever sense this view seemed to make in the days after the ending of the capital punishment laws and privileges in Israel, it is highly unlikely that adultery per se was intended by the words: “the nakedness of a thing” (the literal translation of the words in question). Kaiser summarizes Murray’s objections, which are classic:



The Pentateuch prescribed death for adultery (Lev. 20:10; Deut. 22:22; cf. 22:23-27);




Numbers 5:11-31 even cared for cases of suspected but unproved adultery, so that could not be the intention of this provision;




Deuteronomy 22:13-21 also covered the case of a bride who was charged with previous sexual promiscuity and who vindicated herself; so that could not be the alternative meant here;




Deuteronomy 22:23-24 treats the cause of a betrothed virgin who voluntarily defiled herself. The sanction was death for both;




Nor can the “unseemly thing” of Deuteronomy 24:1 be a matter of coercing a bride-to-be to have sexual relations, for Deuteronomy 22:25-27 exonerated the virgin and put the man to death;




Nor was it a matter of premarital sex between an unbetrothed man and woman, for in that case the man must marry her and never divorce her (Deut. 22:18-19).108



This sort of reasoning seems conclusively to rule out simple adultery as the meaning of the words.
… is “Unseemly Behavior Short of Adultery”
The second option is that these words stand for some behavior that is unseemly but is short of adultery. This was the view of Shammai himself.109 The majority of modern commentators seem to side with this option.110 Like Shammai, they include in this category such things as immodesty of dress (e.g., going out without a veil) or of action (e.g., spinning yarn in the streets, an activity of prostitutes awaiting their next client). Of course after the ending of capital punishment, adultery would be included.
In favor of this view is the use of nakedness in the Old Testament as an offense-term and a term with sexual connotations (cf. Exod. 20:26; Lev. 18; etc.). Additionally, the only other use of the two terms is in Deuteronomy 23:14, which is in the immediate context of poor hygienic practices (i.e., improper toilet hygiene).

Welcome! I really hope you get the help you are searching for. Yes, Jesus taught there was only one excuse for divorce and that was if there was adultery. If both of you committed adultery, then the marriage is broken in God's eyes. I am not an expert in this though, so I just hope you find the help you are looking for,

The God we serve is supremely kind and very, very gracious - more than any of us can imagine.  God is more willing to forgive that we are willing to ask!  We are told that God is "faithful and just to forgive us our sins and cleanse us from all unrighteousness"  Claim that promise!

Problem is being a perpetual adultery from and adulterous marriage

You say you need serious help. What help was it that you were looking for ?

I'm look for the true answer about remarriage is it perpetual adultery. Can someone please help me figure it out. If it is point me to the verses.

@Elizabeth Lawrence, The real problem is you're being beat up by GUILT. The remedy is  sincere repentance. The FACT is that Jesus already carried your guilt and your punishment by being nailed to the cross and being tortured to death. That's plenty of payment! And God is greater than your tormented conscience. So stop sinning! Jesus tells us in John 15 that we are continually being cleansed by God so we can focus on bearing the fruit of the Spirit in our lives:  love, joy, peace, patience, kindness, goodness, faithfulness, gentleness and self-control. Focus on these. Stay in the Word. Pray.

Ok so if I'm feeling guilt that means I am doing something wrong. So I need to divorce and leave and pray and keep with the Lord. Thank you makes sense ^_^. I'll tell my family today.

The woman who hath a husband is bound by the law to her husband as long as her husband liveth, says Paul the apostle in Romans 7:2. This is because God has made male and female in the first creation in order to demonstrate and express the 'great mystery of Christ and the Church', as to the New Creation, Ephesians 5:32.

This question is essentially asking about making a domestic decision, but on a site that only interprets specific Bible passages. Consider two things: 1. the answers you seem to seek personal advice, which the Christianity.SE explains we don't do. 2. Here, you could ask the meaning of specific passages only, but not with your own story in the question. I do hope you can find friends or counselors or someone to get good advice from, but we just can't get into that specifically here on this site.

If you want specific church doctrines about this, you might consider a search on Christianity.SE: divorce and remarriage.

Ya that's what I trying to figure out is the meaning to the bible passages and other bible passages that may relate that I'm not aware of yet. I need bibical evidence to make a clear decision to do but I want to have more understanding before I myself make that decision

No, feeling guilty doesn't necessarily mean you're doing something wrong! See I John 3:20. Even the Apostle Paul doesn't provide legal requirements concerning divorce and remarriage in I Corinthians 7, only recommendations. I believe that God has a plan for your life and you should be at peace as you follow the leading of the Holy Spirit. Submit your future into God's hands through prayer.

Ya I've decided to just keep separate keep studying and praying til the YHWH gives me the answer.

I want to know the answer though it's like a piece of a puzzle and its driving me out of mine wanting to know the answer.

God does forgive.  Jesus gave His life so that we can be restored to God.
1 John 1:9

If we confess our sins, he is faithful and just to forgive us our
sins, and to cleanse us from all unrighteousness.

Isaiah 1:18

Come now, and let us reason together, saith the LORD: though your sins
be as scarlet, they shall be as white as snow; though they be red like
crimson, they shall be as wool.

Paul addresses the church in Corinth and exposes that some of them had been guilty of fornication and adultery – but they were forgiven (1 Corinthians 6:9-11).

Know ye not that the unrighteous shall not inherit the kingdom of God?
Be not deceived: neither fornicators, … nor adulterers, … shall
inherit the kingdom of God. And such were some of you: but ye are
washed, but ye are sanctified, but ye are justified in the name of the
Lord Jesus, and by the Spirit of our God.

You are right to search for salvation as a pearl of great price (Matthew 13:45-46).  It is worth every cost or sacrifice to gain salvation.  Consider Matthew 5:29-30.

And if thy right eye offend thee, pluck it out, and cast it from thee:
for it is profitable for thee that one of thy members should perish,
and not that thy whole body should be cast into hell. And if thy right
hand offend thee, cut it off, and cast it from thee: for it is
profitable for thee that one of thy members should perish, and not
that thy whole body should be cast into hell.

It is not biblical or logical that divorce is the remedy for your guilt.  You are suffering guilt from divorce (among other things).  Another divorce will not free you from guilt.  Another divorce will further complicate your situation and likely hurt your husband and your children.
While you will not find forgiveness without repentance, neither will you find forgiveness in your own attempts to merit salvation.  Trust God to forgive you, and trust God to lead you in paths of righteousness.
Galatians 2:16

Knowing that a man is not justified by the works of the law, but by
the faith of Jesus Christ, even we have believed in Jesus Christ, that
we might be justified by the faith of Christ, and not by the works of
the law: for by the works of the law shall no flesh be justified.


This is a good response. Better than any response that I could make.

Problem is being a perpetual adultery from and adulterous marriage

Scripture does not support the concept of perpetual adultery or an adulterous marriage.  Divorce is not part of God's plan; divorce is harmful, hurtful and destructive.  Look at this article https://www.davidservant.com/im-divorced-and-remarried-am-i-living-in-adultery-part-3/
